# How to get the data list as JSON String

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Inner Lists are not return as a JSON String.. only the first data list is return...

Is there any way to get all data as JSON string ?

------My method ---------------------

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mainreservationChart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getMRChartData(@ModelAttribute ("ReservationSummaryRQDTO") ReservationSummaryRQDTO search){

    ReservationSummaryDTO returnDataDTO = new ReservationSummaryDTO();

    MainReservationChartWSImpl wsImpl = MRWSUtil.getInstance().getWS_ServicePort();

    search.setHotelCode("BBH");
    search.setReportDate(toXmlDateGMT(new Date()));

    returnDataDTO = wsImpl.getReservationSummary(search);

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("status", true);
    model.put("hotelCode", returnDataDTO.getHotelCode());
    model.put("summary", returnDataDTO.getSummaryMonth());
    model.put("data", returnDataDTO);

    return new ModelAndView("jsonView", model);

}
```

---

DTOs

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "reservationSummaryDTO", propOrder = {
    "hotelCode",
    "summaryMonth"
})
public class ReservationSummaryDTO {

    protected String hotelCode;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<SummaryMonthDTO> summaryMonth;
}
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "summaryMonthDTO", propOrder = {
    "month",
    "summaryType"
})
public class SummaryMonthDTO {

    protected String month;
    @XmlElement(nillable = false)
    protected List<SummaryTypeDTO> summaryType;
}
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "summaryTypeDTO", propOrder = {
    "date",
    "displaySequence",
    "total",
    "typeCode"
})
public class SummaryTypeDTO {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<SummaryDateDTO> date;
    protected Integer displaySequence;
    protected Double total;
    protected String typeCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mainreservationChart", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
```

Comment: still not getting  the full data lists as JSON string..adding the above is giving me following error                                HTTP Status 406 --- The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Comment: how do you test the controlleres? using a rest client?

Comment: try  adding Content-Type:application/json ,Accept:application/json as two header request form the client side

Comment: Managed to resolved it..@RequestMapping(value="/mainreservationChart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody ModelMap getMRChartData(@ModelAttribute ("ReservationSummaryRQDTO") ReservationSummaryRQDTO search){